# Extending UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITableViewController. Now the view for adding a new entry and editing an entry are the same so I  would like to extend them.

I have an EntryViewController implemented with the UI defined in an xib.

In the storyboard I have the TableViewController and with the plus on top right I segue to the AddEntryViewController.

The AddEntryViewController is defined to extend the EntryViewController.

What happens is that the AddEntryViewController loads with an empty screen, so the labels from the EntryViewController are not rendered. In prepare for segue I see that the AddEntryViewController is instantiated.

Latter I will also have an EditEntryViewController which will also extend from EntryViewController.

Why is the screen empty?

Comment: What code do you use to segue to `EntryViewController`?

Comment: Posting code would be helpful... Where are you instantiating the view from nib? Are you calling [super ...] in viewDidLoad: ? If your second controller is instantiated by the storyboard, initWithCoder: will be called, so make sure your view from nib instantiation isn't in the unreachable place for the second controller to be called.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem by removing the view from the Storyboard. And then calling initWithNibName